# Proportionately resize image to fit height of containing div

Tags: css

How do I resize image to be the same height as the li height? Here's the HTML:

```
<header>
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li>Home</li>
            <li>About</li>
            <li>Contact</li>
            <li><img src="images/grid.png"></li>
            <li>Sign In</li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</header>
```

And this is what I did for CSS:

```
header nav {
    text-align: right;
    margin-right: 22px;
}

header nav ul li { 
    display: inline;
    font-family: Arial;
    padding: 3px;
    margin-right: 6px;
}

header nav ul li img { 
    max-height: 100%;
}
```

Max-height doesn't work. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You must explicitly set `height` for `<li>`, otherwise `max-height` of child `<img>` won't work.

Also, change `<li>`'s `display:inline` to `display:inline-block` to allow height settings.